# How to make the readonly checkbox to disable-true?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

The checkbox is disabled readOnly. In that checkbox, I have tried to use the following code but it's  not working.

```
$(".FlagClass").prop("disabled", true);
```

I need to disable true in the checkbox

Comment: What do you want? You want to check a disabled checkbox using jQuery?

Comment: Please provide the full code, including the HTML for the checkbox

Answer (score 1):

Try with attr instead

```
$(".FlagClass").attr("disabled", false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with **disabled**?

```
$(".FlagClass").prop("disabled", 'disabled');
```

or

```
$(".FlagClass").attr("disabled", true);
```

Answer (score 0):

if the class is in an input type element:

```
$('.FlagClass').attr('readonly',false);
```

if you want to remove the attribute that you have

```
$(".FlagClass").removeAttr('readonly');
```

Or:

```
$('.FlagClass').removeAttr('disabled');
```

also

```
$('.FlagClass').attr('disabled', false);
```